# Json4s ignores @JsonProperty jackson annotations

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

I have this code

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import org.json4s.DefaultFormats
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}

object Testing extends App {
    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
    val json =
            """
              |{
              |"1strange_field_name":"name"
              |}
            """.stripMargin
    println(read[Test](json))
}

case class Test(@JsonProperty("1strange_field_name") testName: Option[String])
```

It should be printing Test(Some(name)) but it's printing Test(None). This is caused by the fact that json4s is not using the @JsonProperty annotation. Is there a way to configure json4s to use the jackson annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the easiest way to solve this is to use the exact field name by using ``

```
case class Test(`1strange_field_name`: Option[String])
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why not simply use: 1strange_field_name without ``. It doesn't actually answer the question. The whole point is to use a different naming convention in the scala code and when creating the JSON itself

Comment: it is my own question... so I think I understand it

Comment: 1strange_field_name is an invalid identifier is Scala

Comment: This works good: case class Test(1strange_field_name: Option[String]). It will use the name of the case class property as the field of the JSON. No need for ``. Anyway, The whole point, as also written in your own code is to have a JSON field with a name different than the case class property name (using @JsonProperty).

Comment: No ofense, but please don't explain me my own quetion... the whole point was to be able to parse the json into a case class without having to write a custom parser. `case class Test(1strange_field_name: Option[String])` does not compile in Scala 2.10, 2.11, 2.12 or 2.13 so I am not sure how are you compiling your code